# Meta to close extra body width - For Mobile?

Tags: html, mobile-safari

I'm trying the code below; but it wont work. My content's width renders about just right in my Android Incredible, and I think it renders across pretty well in iPhone *(Think, I am using online emulators for iPhone view, but should be)*

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
```

But the grey #999 background is still causing a horizontal scroll - and seems to not be adapting like everything else. How can I close that extra space in background created by the `body {` ??

Comment: What about `width=device-width`?

Comment: Nope; just plugged that in and still same ugly horizontal scroll. I've also tried setting the body width with media queries and still nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the content in your page is causing the horizontal scroll.  Once you get the page too narrow, the youtube video and images cause the scroll.

Comment: This sounds like it might become a solution. I originally had all the images at the 'img' to re-size responsively, then it broke my slide show as those images were using 'img' so I need to figure out how to apply the 're-size class' to the all the sites images aside from the slider ones. As soon as I plug this in, I'll let you know how it goes. But why would the images/videos create extra space in the body?